# The system saves the records that fired the before trigger after the trigger finishes execution?

Tags: subquery

```
trigger HelloWorldTrigger on Account (before insert) {
    for(Account a : Trigger.New) {
        a.Description = 'New description';
    }   
}
```

Copy

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as mentioned in [Context Variable Considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm):

> You can use an object to change its own field values using trigger.new, but only in before triggers. In all after triggers, trigger.new is not saved, so a runtime exception is thrown.

You can read more features and limitations in the documentation link above.